# How to reverse replace remove Strings without any inbuilt methods

Tags: java, string, algorithm, replace, reverse

How can we achieve reverse, replace , remove operation on a String.  I was at interview, interviewer asked me to write a logic to for below.

- input: "This is an interview"
- if we have t replace it with z
- Remove the spaces
- reverse the sentence completely
- Write logic without using any inbuilt methods***

I couldn't able to break the string and compare like how we can do incase of Integers using % and / operators. I requested him to use one inbuilt method charAt(); to achieve that. But is there way to achieve without using charAt() method too?.

```
        String input = "This is an interview";
        char t = 't';
        char z = 'z';
        char space = ' ';
        String output = "";
        char c = 'i';
        for(int i=0;;i++){
            try{
                c = input.charAt(i);     //here I have used one inbuilt method but how can we avoid this
            }catch(Exception e){
                break;
            }
         
            if(c==t) {
                output = z + output;
           }else if(c!=space){ 
                output = c+output;  
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Comment: To be precise, do you want to avoid only String's inbuilt methods?

Comment: No otherwise I would have used String builder. Any inbuilt method using dot.

Comment: @JagadishDabbiru you can't do it without invoking methods on `String`.

Comment: One way you could get around this (weird) interview question is, to redefine `input` as `char[]` (if that is maybe allowed, who knows). Then you could simply iterate the characters in the char array. Otherwise, I don't see a way without using any inbuilt methods.

Comment: When I debug chartAt method. It is using something this field in String class `@Stable
    private final byte[] value;`. Is there way get this field using reflection?

Comment: @JagadishDabbiru Reflection is based on classes so you would still need to use *their* methods (which are included in "Any inbuilt method using dot" as you earlier stated).

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, agree :(

Comment: I am afraid that to answer this question we would need to know full context which only interviewer could provide. Without it answer would be *it is impossible* (unless we actually allow some things not mentioned yet). For instance maybe by *string* interviewer didn't mean `String` as a class, but *any series of characters* which could also include `char[]` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an array of characters (char[ ]) instead of an string, and use [ ] for accessing the different characters instead of charAt.

```
char input[] = {'T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', 'n', ' ', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'v', 'i', 'e', 'w'};
int size = 20;
String output = "";
for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(input[i] == 't')
        output += "c";
    else if(input[i] != ' ')
        output += input[i];
}
System.out.println(output);
```

This code has been tested.

```
Input: This is an interview
Output: weivrecninasisihT
```

Comment: From title "How to reverse replace remove `String`s..." not `char[]` so I am not sure if this would help OP (although I like thinking outside the box).